# How to get .PSD Photoshop thumbnails to show in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, thumbnails, psd

I have a problem where thumbnails for Photoshop (PSD) files won't show in Windows 10. Instead, only the default program icon for PSD files is shown. Thumbnails for other image files are working perfectly.

- Now the strange thing - this problems happens only on one machine. On another (freshly reinstalled) there are no problems.
- I am not using any third party software on either machine.

**Configuration**:

```
Both machines are Windows 10 (v. 2004) (OS Build 19041.450).
Photoshop is v. 21.2.1.265.
```

I have reinstalled Photoshop, cleaned up with CCleaner after uninstalling, restarted etc.

These are my settings in File explorer:

[image: PSD thumbnails not showing in Windows 10]

I have read on Superuser threads that people are using SageThumbs and similar but I want to avoid that since it seems to work 'out of the box' on the freshly installed Windows 10.

What can it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible without a 3rd party app. There has been numerous requests to both Adobe and Microsoft for this feature but they seem to be in a stalemate regarding this issue.

Just accept the defeat and install https://sourceforge.net/projects/sagethumbs/

Answer (score 1):

https://poppeman.se/pictus/
download pictus
open it.
open a .psd file in it
the 'codec' to open psd files ends up in explorer and all psd files will open in Explorer ever after
I have been looking for this solution for months!!!!!

Comment: Does this create thumbnails like the question asks or just open `.psd`s like your answer mentions?

Comment: The question was...
"I have a problem where thumbnails for Photoshop (PSD) files won't show in Windows 10." With this method the thumbnails for PSD files show in Windows 10 so, yes, it just opens .psd's but it means you can glance down Explorer and see all the images, as thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to see the preview for multi-layered .psd files with Sagethumbs, you need to increase the `maximum size of image file` setting in the Sagethumb settings. Go to the Sagethumb settings and increase the number for `maximum size of image file` until you can see the preview for your files.

As a graphic artist, I have `.psd` files with dozens of layers- I only had to change the setting from the default setting of 100mb to 200mb before I was able to see their preview as thumbnails:

[image: Sagethumbs menu]