# Why are Photoshop .psd thumbnails now showing in Windows 10 file explorer without installing anything?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, psd

Are Windows 10 File Explorer thumbnails now available for .PSD images without a plugin? I have NOT added any add-ons like **SageThumbs** and suddenly they are showing up! **See screenshot below.**

This has not been available natively without a plugin for years - [How to get .PSD Photoshop thumbnails to show in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1579687/how-to-get-psd-photoshop-thumbnails-to-show-in-windows-10)

I don't see anything in the Photoshop release notes. If this is not related to a new **Photohop** version, could it possibly be related to a **Windows PowerTools** update (which I do have installed)? If so, I cannot find anything in that documentation either.

Is anyone else seeing this?

[image]

Comment: No. This is a welcome capability that has been missing in Windows File Manager. My question is to understand where this capability is coming from.

Comment: Good to know. Did you recent restart Windows or perform an OS update? My guess is there was a patch that fixed this and your system simply patched it and that’s that.

Comment: Could be.  The .psd file extension is the main Photoshop file format.  For a while Adobe shipped with a component that provided this thumbnail capability but they actually removed it when they started promoting Adobe Bridge - which was very annoying. 
Trying to understand if it is something just on my machine or what - before getting too excited...

Comment: As seen on an Adobe-related forum, thumbnails for `.psd` and other Adobe file types have technically not been available in Windows for some time due to issues between Microsoft and Adobe, which required using third-party software for that. Apparently an agreement has now been reached.

Comment: harrymc - Can you reproduce that .psd thumbnails now work without a plugin?